# How to load URL in a textfield in xcode when any website is selected?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have created an app which is a web browser. Whenever I enter any URL in text field it goes to the required web page. I have included an UIWebView to display webpage. By default google website is opened. But when I select any website from google I want to display that URL in the textfield. How do I do it?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.myTextField.text = @"http://www.google.com";
  NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
  NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
  [_myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
  self.myTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      self.myTextField.text = @"http://www.google.com";
      NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
      NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
      [_myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
      _myWebView.delegate = self;
      self.myTextField.delegate = self;
    }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
{
    NSURL *requestURL       = [webView.request URL];
    txtView.text   = [requestURL absoluteString];

}
```

Comment: It works. But the problem is when I click on any website while loading the URL is displayed. But when actual page is shown, the URL changes or becomes about:blank. Is it supposed to display like this?